# How to push new values into array when checkbox is checked and remove when unchecked using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I just started learning vue.js, I have such a problem, I have dynamic data which I render with 'v-for' loop, Also I have an empty array where I want to push checked checkbox data, and remove this data  after uncheck, also I am trying to update new array if any of object data will change, for example, if I push first object into an empty array and then update the quantity value I don't want to push a new object But also want to update existing

```js
const app = new Vue({ 
  el: '#app', 
  data: () => ({ 
  
   products:[
 { itemId:'330012929', name:'testBook', cashBack:'3.00', price:12.99, quantity:1},
  { itemId:'330012922', name:'testBook2', cashBack:'4.00', price:12.2, quantity:1},
     ]
  }),
  
  methods:{
    pushValue(arg){
     console.log(arg)
    }
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div v-for='(x,index) in  products' :key='index'>
      <div><span><input type='checkbox' @change='pushValue(x)'><span>item id: {{x.itemId}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <input type='checkbox' @change='pushValue(x)'> Put  v-model in this input. Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ul class="category__list">
      <li v-for="(category, index) in categoriesData[categoryTitle]" :key="index">
        <input type="checkbox" :value="category" v-model="selectedCategories"> 
               {{category}}
      </li>
   </ul>
```

If you use v-model on checkbox input and declare it as array Vue will automaticly do the job for you.
SelectedCategories array will be checked boxes.